в ничто (indeclinable?)
This is from РОССІЯ И ЕВРЕИ (1924):

Пока духъ въ богатырѣ не угасъ, а рука его не ослабла, онъ не искалъ
равенства въ смерти, въ гибели, въ уничтоженіи, въ Ничто.

I think в ничто means "in nothingness", but we see it is not declined. Shouldn't this be не в чём or в ничём? Is there anything unusual about the sentence above? Or maybe ничто to mean "nothingness" and not "nothing" is itself unusual, accounting for a reluctance to decline it?


Is there anything unusual about the sentence above?

Yes, very much so.
The pronouns ничто and никто (in their direct sense) don't behave like regular Russian nominals.
First, they require double negation: никто не обнимет необъятного; никто не забыт, ничто не забыто, etc.
Second, when used with prepositions, the prepositions go between не and the pronoun: ни о чём, ни к кому and so on.
Sometimes people want to use these pronouns parenthetically, as nouns. For instance, to convey the concept of "nothingness", as in your example, or, say, to translate the moniker "Nobody" that Odyssey assumed in the cyclops's cave.
The usual patterns can't be used anymore, because it would change the meaning: он не искал равенства ни в чём means "he wasn't looking for equality in anything" which has a completely different meaning. So the speaker is faced with a tough choice.
The first option is to treat the noun as a regular neuter noun with the regular neuter declension pattern, similar to зерно or седло, and decline it accordingly.
This approach yields gems like the following:

Мальвина: Предположим, что у вас в кармане два яблока. Некто взял у вас одно яблоко. Сколько у вас осталось яблок?
Буратино: Два.
Мальвина: Почему?
Буратино: Я же не отдам некту яблоко, хоть он дерись!

or

ничто мне чуждо и его я
по человечески не чту
себя противопоставляя
ничту

This is cute, but it's a word play, and looks and feels like it.
Another option is treat it as an indeclinable noun. That's what the author is doing, because this text is a serious prose and there's no place for word play in it.
Note that this kind of secondary derivation (parts of speech produced from other parts of speech that are irregular) is usually solved by dropping all possible irregularities across most languages. That's why they say "they no-goed the project", "the batter flied out" and similar.

Пока духъ въ богатырѣ не угасъ, а рука его не ослабла, онъ не искалъ равенства въ смерти, въ гибели, въ уничтоженіи, въ Ничто.
«Ничто» here means "nothingness".When «ничто» means "nothing", it is declined.
If it were "nothing", it would be «нИ в чём»

That's what I initially thought, but looking at Quassnoi's reply, I see that не искал не в чём would mean "not in anything".

OK, thank you. I see now. And thank you for the correction.
